# Page break is not working

Tags: jquery, css, printing

I have a table with multiple rows and borders for each row. I have an option to print the page with the help of a jquery plugin `print.js`. When I try to print, the `<tr>` is breaking. Some portion is on one page, remaining is on the next.

```
<div id="printable_allagenda" style="display: none;" ></div>
```

Jquery: Click event for printing

```
$("#print_agenda").click(function(){

       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",   
           url: "module/parents/calendar/print_loader_tableview.php", 
           data: data_values,
           success: function(msg){ 
                $('#printable_allagenda').html(msg);
                $('#printable_allagenda').print();
           }
       }); 
       return false; 
    });
```

CSS:

```css
@media print {
body{
    max-width:99%; 
     page-break-before: avoid; 
}
    #printable_allagenda{
        font-size: 12px;
    }
      table.gridtable {
        font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
        font-size:11px;
        color:#333333;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: #666666;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    table.gridtable th {
        border-width: 1px;
        padding: 8px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #666666;
        background-color: #dedede;
    }
    table.gridtable td {
        border-width: 1px;
        padding: 8px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #666666;
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }   
    @page {
    margin: 0.5cm;
    }
}
 table.gridtable {
    font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
    color:#333333;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #666666;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.gridtable th {
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #666666;
    background-color: #dedede;
}
table.gridtable td {
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #666666;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.fadedyes{
    position: absolute;top:0;left:0;width: 100%;height:100%;z-index:2;opacity:0.4;filter: alpha(opacity = 50);
}
```

I have tried giving properties for the table`table.gridtable` with this style:`page-break-inside: avoid;`
Also used style for `table.gridtable tr` with style:`page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto`, but it's not working.

I have attached a screen shot.

[image]

Comment: A quick test shows that `page-break-inside` works on `tr` elements in the latest browsers. (IE, Mozilla, Chrome. Can't test Edge or Safari.) So... can you show the HTML you're trying?

Answer (score 0):

Use `float:none` or `display:block` for parent elements and make `page-break-before:always`